# Opencv:error: (-210) in function threshold

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to estimate the bounding box for simple numpy array based images

```
ret,thresh = cv.threshold(img1[:,:,244],10,255,0)
```

The output looks like this:

[image: The thresholded image]

Next I do this

```
im2,contours,hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
```

I get an error

```
FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function cvStartFindContours_Impl
```

So i convert to

```
im2,contours,hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh.astype(np.int8), 1, 2)
```

Now I get the error

```
error: (-210)  in function threshold
```

How can I solve the error? Are their altervatives how do I go about getting the tilted bounding box for the example?

The array before conversion to np.uint8 :

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   ...,
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

The array after conversion:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   ...,
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: Can you paste the value of `thresh` before and after converting it to `np.int8`?

Comment: @keineahnung2345 added it

Comment: The array is too large, maybe you should use `np.unique(thresh)` to better explore it.

Comment: @keineahnung2345 before it is `array([  0., 255.])` and after it is `array([-1,  0], dtype=int8)`

Comment: It would be a good idea not to use magic numbers all over the code (4th parameter of `threshold`, 2nd and 3rd parameter of `findContours`.) Not sure about you, but to me `cv2.RETR_LIST` is a lot more meaningful than a `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion:

```
thresh = np.array([255, 0])
thresh.astype(np.int8) #array([-1,  0], dtype=int8)
```

gives you a wrong answer because of overflow.

You should instead use:

```
thresh.astype(np.uint8) #array([255,   0], dtype=uint8)
```

so that the result will be correct.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks. I got the same problem while using `findTransformECC` with the `inputMask` parameter.